# Amazon SDK Java v2 S3Client listObjects throws S3Exception

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I have saved files on `AWS S3` imitating folder structure using names.

e.g. A file `sample.jpeg` under `ABC` folder will be named `ABC/sample.jpeg`

I am trying to programmatically delete these folders using the Java SDK v2. I'm trying to list these files using `prefix`.

e.g. In the example above, I'm trying to list all files having prefix `ABC` in the bucket.

What's problematic is that without this prefix, the SDK lists the files just fine, but the prefix in my `ListObjectsRequest` as I have shown in the code below, it throws `s3Exception`. The exception itself has an `awsErrorDetails` attribute that has a `sdkHttpResponse` wrapping `statusCode` : `302` and `statusText` : `"Moved Temporarily"`

Following is the Exception trace:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 302, Request ID: null)
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleErrorResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:115) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.handleResponse(HandleResponseStage.java:73) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:58) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.HandleResponseStage.execute(HandleResponseStage.java:41) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:64) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:36) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:77) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:39) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.doExecute(RetryableStage.java:113) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(RetryableStage.java:86) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:62) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:42) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:57) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:37) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:240) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:96) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:120) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:73) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:44) ~[sdk-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55) ~[aws-core-2.7.22.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.DefaultS3Client.listObjects(DefaultS3Client.java:2278) ~[s3-2.7.22.jar:na]
```

Here's the code snippet I'm using:

```
    ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = ListObjectsRequest.builder()
            .bucket(this.bucketName)
            .prefix(path)
            .build();

    List<ObjectIdentifier> objectIds = s3client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest)
            .contents()
            .stream()
            .map(s3Object -> ObjectIdentifier.builder().key(s3Object.key()).build())
            .collect(toList());
```

Following are the dependencies from my `pom.xml`:

```
      <properties>
           <aws-sdk.version>2.7.22</aws-sdk.version>
      </properties>

    ...

        <!-- Amazon Web Services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>auth</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-sdk.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you using 'ABC/' as prefix, refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsRequest.html

Comment: @Ironluca I have tried with and without delimiters and it doesn't work either way. At this point, I would like to point out that downgrading the version to `2.15.x` actually solved my problem. But the error still remains incomprehensible.

Comment: @Yash Version `2.15.x` does not exist. Which version did you *actually* downgrade to? Can you keep incrementing the patch/minor versions until you find the version that throws the exception?

Comment: @Jacob G. Extremely sorry for the confusion. Below is the version I fell back to:
`<aws-sdk.version>2.5.15</aws-sdk.version>`

Comment: @Yash No problem :) thanks for the quick response. I do a lot of work with AWS v2, and I've never seen something like this before. Is `2.5.15` the latest version of the SDK that **doesn't** throw the exception? If I'm able to reproduce your exception, I'd be happy to open an issue on their GitHub repository

Comment: Furthermore, I just want to know if this behaviour of the newer version is expected at all or it is a bug. Because if it is a desirable addition, I would change my code to comply with the newer constructs.

Comment: @Jacob G. I haven't tried to step-wise upgrade the version due to lack of time at that moment, which in retrospect seems the obvious thing to do. I would do that and update the post here. The intent to the question was also partly to see if other developers are facing a similar issue

Comment: Well I've never seen that exception myself, but I'll see if I can reproduce it using the same version/code that you used.

Comment: It looks like I'm not able to reproduce the exception; It simply returns the object for me: `ObjectIdentifier(Key=sample.jpeg)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198376/discussion-between-yash-and-jacob-g).

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with aws's internal dependency on `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient`.

The minimum required version for `httpclient` is `4.5.9`. If you downgrade that version in your project pom, then this problem will arise.

To check what version you're running, try:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Find out the `httpclient` version. This is what mine looks like:

```
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:apache-client:jar:2.8.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.10:runtime
[INFO] |  |  |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.11:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.12:runtime
```

**Solution:**
If you've downgraded the version by using any bom or dependency management (in my case `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.1.5.RELEASE` caused this to happen), then just add this to your pom & it should work:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Related Issues:
[Issue#1434](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1434),   [Issue#1919](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/1919),    [Issue#1372](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1372)

Answer (score 1):

Adding the below dependency to the pom file will resolve this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as our discussion in the comments hasn't led anywhere, I'd rather not see this bounty go to waste.

I've run your code on my machine (using the same AWS SDK version), and I'm not able to reproduce the exception. If you're still experiencing the issue, I recommend opening an issue explaining your problem on the GitHub repository: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/new

I've been through this process before, and they normally respond within a couple days.

Please report back if they manage to resolve your issue!

Comment: Hey @Jacob G. Thanks for your efforts. I agree there is no point in letting the bounty die.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible for you to have a comparison between the instance of the `s3client` (between older version and problematic new version AWS SDK for Java). Please share.

Might have to debug and inspect. Likely there are values that could be different in default between the 2. For example if default region is different, you won't get your previously saved objects using the new SDK without changes.

Also, since you are migrating to a major revision, it's likely possible that you will find more issues down the road. It could guide you to refer to the [Migration Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/migration-guide/what-is-java-migration.html).

If you just want specific changes to look up you can check this [What's Different Page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/migration-guide/whats-different.html). Please check the links inside that page on the Change Log, you'll get a per method comparison what changed.

Comment: I have already mentioned in the comment above that downgrading the version solves the problem. So, this answer does not address the situation. I am not relying upon the default region of the SDK for saving or deleting the files. Furthermore, I can still list the files using a terminal, it is just with this API and just with the prefix that the files are not getting listed.
So, downvoting your answer to avoid confusion.
You are also, wrong in assuming that `2.15.x` to `2.24.x` is a major version upgrade.

Comment: At the tail end of that comment you mentioned "But the error still remains incomprehensible." and have not marked this question solved. You also did not initially mention from which version you are migrating from and which specific version you are migrating to. In the code shared you gave 2.7.x and you said you "downgrade" to 2.15.x fixed it. Please mark correspondingly if you don't need further assistance here.

Comment: I request you to please go through the original question again. Downgrading the library is mitigating the issue and not solving it. The actual concern here is the code failing only with prefixes.

Answer (score -1):

I did come across a similar error before. The error is caused because AWS guys have started transitioning their APIs to v2 for the 2.x SDK. Below is the code snippet that works perfect with or without prefix.

```
ListObjectsV2Request request = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(bucketName).withPrefix(prefix)
                    .withDelimiter(GenericConstants.FORWARD_SLASH);
ListObjectsV2Result result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(request);
```

Feel free to ask for further details if needed. I have did quite a lot with the v2 APIs of S3.